# Caption Filter works in Preview, but not in regular view of node

Tags: media, entities

I am using the caption filter module, which is working fine on a couple sites I manage, but on one specific site, when I use the markup and click on preview, it works perfectly, but if I save the node and then view it normally, it is clear that filter is not processing as it outputs the filter markup as plain text.

I am mystified as to why an input filter would work in preview, but not after its is saved.  I keep thinking it might be a permissions issue, but I can't identify anything that would seem to trigger this.

Any suggestions to narrowing down this issue would be greatly appreciated.  And I do have the caption filter as the last one, per the instructions and same with a similar site that I do not have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured this issue out.  This particular content type was using a custom template and I forgot to push the body content through check_markup(..) before outputting it.